# How to put h4() and selectInput in-line

Tags: r

I am new in shiny, I wonder how to put the "=" close beside the selectInput box?

```
library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    titlePanel("Calculation:"),#Voltage calculation
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             selectInput("selc11", h4("Cable"),#Resistivity
                         choices = list("Copper" = 0.0174, "Alum" = 0.0282), selected = 1)),
      h4("=")
    )
  )
)
server = function(input, output) {

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `shiny` relies a bit on CSS, so you'll likely need to read how to do that. There have been other shiny-related questions on SO that have to do with layout (not specifically `h4`), so if you generalize your question a little you should be able to find something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this:

[image]

You can achive it with:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui = fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  mainPanel(
    titlePanel("Calculation:"),#Voltage calculation
    fluidRow(
      column(1, h4('Cable')),
      column(3, selectInput(
        "selc11",
        label = '',
        choices = list("Copper" = 0.0174, "Alum" = 0.0282), selected = 1)
      ),
      column(3, h4("="))
    )
  )
)
server = function(input, output) {
  runjs("$('label.control-label').remove()")
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```